# Text manipulation - create multiple entries from a single entry

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I want to know if there is a way to use the following entry:

`Game: Army Men: Sarge's HeroesDreamcast (2000), Nintendo 64 (1999), PlayStation (2000) and Windows (2000)`

and create 3 entries programmatically in python:

`Game: Army Men: Sarge's HeroesDreamcast (2000) Nintendo 64 (1999)`
`Game: Army Men: Sarge's HeroesDreamcast (2000) PlayStation (2000)`
`Game: Army Men: Sarge's HeroesDreamcast (2000) Windows (2000)`

I guess one would have to split on the commas and the 'and' and then concatenate the first part with the other parts.

Comment: Have you tried your guess yet?

Comment: Yep. It works. But its rather long - I was hoping for an easier/more compact answer. This is what do - (1) use re.split() on ',' or 'and' (2) strip whitespace and (3) write a for loop that pastes the first entry with the rest.